# Reproducir audio con JavaScript DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first

Tags: javascript, html, dom

no puedo reproducir `audio` desde código, me arroja este error

```
DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first.
```

pensé que era por una promesa así que le agregué un `async/await` pero nada

```
  <audio  id="audio" src="{{ url('/mp3/audio.mp3 }}" ></audio>

  var audio= document.getElementById("audio");

  socket.on('server/cliente', async function(res) {
    if (me == res.to) {
      await audio.play();
    }
  });
```

Comment: Desde cierto punto los navegadores bloquean el atributo audioplay y ademas no se puede reproducir un audio sin que el usuario no haya interactuado con el mouse o con el teclado en la pagina de primeras, es decir, bastaria con cualquier interaccion, siempre y cuando sea un evento directamente ligado a los perifericos como lo son mouse o teclado, y en algunos casos pantalla. Prueba a meter la reproduccion de tu sonido en un evento click y funcionara, que si hay otra forma sin interactuar con el DOM?, nop, no la hay, son restricciones directas del navegador y `JS`.

Comment: Entonces, ahorrandote un poco de dolores de cabeza,  no, no funcionara ni con promesas ni tan poco con delays, cosas como setTimeout, setInterval, y las promesas quedan descartadas..

Comment: Podrías probar con el atributo `autoplay`. Referencia: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio#atributos